# Oracle 12c NetCA silent install prompts for password

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

When I run the NetCA silently on Windows Server 2012 R2, it prompts me to specify a password "Oracle Home User Password". Is there some way that I could provide the password as a parameter or in the response file. I do not see any default property in the netca.rsp but was wondering how to make it completely unattended.

FYI, the output when I run the netca in silent mode. See the last line in the output where it prompts me to specify the password. Also, I am running the command prompt as administrator and I have even tried to login as 'oracle' user account to run the netca, but I run into the same prompt.

```
C:\oracle\product\12.1\dbhome_1\BIN>netca -silent -responsefile "C:\Oracle DB Server and Client\installer\netca.rsp"

Wed May 13 10:42:44 EDT 2015 Oracle Net Configuration Assistant
Parsing command line arguments:
    Parameter "silent" = true
    Parameter "responsefile" = C:\Oracle DB Server and Client\installer\netca.rsp
Done parsing command line arguments.
Oracle Net Services Configuration:
Enter Oracle Home User Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by providing the password in the response file.

```
#SERVICEUSERPASSWORD;String;Windows service user password
# If the oracle home is installed as secure user, supply the password
SERVICEUSERPASSWORD=""<password>""
```

Its a bit confusing when it prompts for "`Oracle Home User Password`" while the property in the response file reads `SERVICEUSERPASSWORD`.